# Setting up AdColony

Tags: ios, iphone, ads

I have an app that I'm about to submit to the app store, but I am having trouble showing the ad. I am only able to show the ad with a button that you have to click as opposed to having it start up automatically. I am using AdColony.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [AdColony configureWithAppID:@"app465e35b9edd249a6af" zoneIDs:@[@"vzdc921461f3ca45049c"] delegate:nil logging:YES];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)sa:(id)sender
{
    [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"vzdc921461f3ca45049c" withDelegate:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? What have you tried?

Comment: This code was put in the AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [AdColony configureWithAppID:@"app465e35b9edd249a6af"
                         zoneIDs:@[@"vzdc921461f3ca45049c"]
                        delegate:nil
                         logging:YES];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
This code was put in the ViewController.m
-(IBAction)sa:(id)sender {
    [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"vzdc921461f3ca45049c" withDelegate:nil];
}

Comment: Code added as edit to post, please delete that comment, next time edit your post instead.